# Is there a way to save a TF2 replay on a server without replays being enabled?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I usally play a lot on public servers, and I sometimes do some crazy things I want to use in a video. But, when I hit the "record that life" button, it says the server does not support replays. Is it possible to still get a recording of it? If so, how?

Comment: To the person who downvoted, can you please leave a comment explaining why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to record TF2 replays on servers with that disabled. However, you can still use a program like [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) to capture your game footage for you. This means you have to have it turned on all the time however, so it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: I have Fraps, but I don't like to use it becuase the CPU it uses.

Comment: @ShadowZ. In that case, you don't have much option other than to turn down your graphics settings while running Fraps. I'm afraid there is no possibility to save a replay if it is disabled on your current server.

Comment: Darn, guess I will have to use decreased graphics for now. I plan on building a new computer, so I assume I will be able to use them both better when it is finished.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Fraps is a pretty big hog when it comes to resources/file size. I'd suggest giving Dxtory a shot as it is a lot lighter on resources and doesn't record completely raw data like Fraps does (or at least did when I used it years ago).

Comment: Shadowplay also works pretty well, but it requires that you have an nVidia Graphics Card

Answer (score 2):

In the latest update of Team Fortress 2, you can create Demos. Those act like replays.
To record them, use

> record filename

That makes the game record your 'Demo' as a .dem file!
To be able to play them back:

> playdemo filename

That's how you play it. An alternative version is if you go to Advanced Settings, and enable Recording Demos in servers. You can do this with any server  or with just Competitive or Casual matchmaking servers.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, no. If you want to make replays, you have to go on a server which supports replays. In the main menu, there is a server tab, there you can manually choose which server to go on as well as the information for if it supports replays. Avoid Valve servers as those never support replays. You can also check the 'Supports Replays' box to make it easier to find a game.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for something that is a reactive (after the fact) recording.

If you have a recent nVidia graphics card (650 or newer), you can turn on [ShadowPlay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay) using the GeForce Experience program.  Shadowplay will record a rolling buffer (up to 20 minutes).  It has a hotkey you can hit when you do something you want to save.

I assume it has some sort of built-in editor to strip it down from 20 minutes to just the part you want... unfortunately, my nVidia cards aren't new enough to use this.

ATI may have something similar, but if they do I'm not aware of it.

As for TF2 itself... there's a plugin called P-REC that can cause TF2 to automatically record demos as you play (using TF2's built-in `record` function).  This is commonly used by high-level players and is [mandatory for league play](http://etf2l.org/help/p-rec/).

Demo files are not movie files and will need to be [converted](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Demo_Video_Creation#Export_to_MOV.2C_new_with_Replay_Update_for_Team_Fortress_2) first.

NOTE:  If you use P-Rec, version 2.0.6 does **not** work.  Use P-Rec 2.0.5 instead.  This is because Valve changed some functionality in the game around, then after 2.0.6 was released to fix P-Rec, Valve changed it back.

Comment: ShadowPlay *can* be a journey to get setup and ensure it works. It also doesn't work well with games played in any mode other than fullscreen. I still support this answer since ShadowPlay is a **great** feature that hopefully continues to grow since its use in gaming is huge.

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJe3Y6XgRM for more than 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Recently, [raptr](http://raptr.com) (it's sortof like a social media platform for games) released a feature that will [automatically record](http://raptr.com/TinyDino/news/5543f1cfd4cdcaa93e/new-gameplay-recording-and-editing-features-in-raptr) all gameplay for all games and give you the ability to edit said recordings. It runs totally in the background and (depending on your graphics card) won't even be able to notice that it's running.